# C# datatypes vs. MySql datatypes

Tags: c#, mysql, types

Does anyone has the list of conversion from MySQL data types to C# data types ? I'm having difficulties when tried to convert from smallint unsigned type into c# type.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the following table for conversion from MySql to C#.

```
MySQL -> C#

char(x) = string
datetime = DateTime
varchar(x) = string
smallint = short
smallint unsigned = ushort
int = int
int unsigned = uint
bigint = long
tinyint = sbyte
tinyint unsigned = byte
bigint unsigned = ulong
text = string
```

Comment: Datetime conversion will give an error, besides what is your source for this?